# jQuery Animate Inline Style

Tags: jquery, css, styles, inline, margin

I am using jQuery to vertically center a div by adding the necessary 'margin-top' to the div as an inline style.

I would like to remove this inline style via a click function and animate the div to 'margin-top: 0'.

So far the only way I have been successful with clearing the inline style is with..

```
jQuery('selector').each(function(idx,el){
    el.style.marginTop='';
});
```

but this make the div jump to the top instead of animating it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

```
jQuery('selector').animate({
    'margin-top' : 0
});
```

Comment: thank you! I thought I tried this earlier but apparently I typed something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$('selector').each(function(idx,el){

      $(el).animate({
            marginTop : 0
        },1000);

});
```